# Redshift "Query execution details" shows a large wait time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In the below query execution details, you can see that is a huge wait time before two phases of the query plan.

Tableau is running this query along with few others(probably 7-10 individual queries) for a dashboard.
It is running in its own queue with 50% memory and 7 slots.
SQA is also enabled. 
I have tried as many options as I can find in the internet forums, I have no idea why this query takes 25 secs, where it actually runs only for few seconds.

Can some one please suggest what could be the reason here.

(BELOW SCREENSHOT FOR QUERY EXECUTION DETAILS)

[image]

Comment: it is either compiling or waiting for a slot. what do you see on STV_WLM_QUERY_STATE while this query is waiting?

Comment: throughout the execution, I see it as running in STV_WLM_QUERY_STATE.

Also, the SVL_QUERY_REPORT shows the different between start and end time in few hundred micro seconds for each step.